# How to attach to and trace method calls of a running .NET application?

Tags: .net, profiling, clr, trace, instrumentation

I'm trying to attach to and trace method calls in a running C# (.NET Framework 4.0) application. I do not have the source code of the application. The research I've done suggests two approaches to this kind of profiling, but I think neither meets my requirements:

1. The .NET Profiling API allows tracing of method calls, but only when profiling is enabled at application launch time; the 'attach' functionality of the profiling API does not support the 'ENTERLEAVE' callback that can be used to trace method calls.
2. IL instrumentation - this approach relies on adding tracing code to the IL of each method when the method is JIT compiled. But in an already-running application, I presume many/most methods are already JIT compiled, so this approach will not be able to trace those methods.

Is the above correct? Can anyone suggest a way to do this kind of profiling?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not have the profiler launch with the app and have it do nothing until you interact with it with another application? That way you can hook the enter/leave/tailcall events.

Comment: Thanks Shaun - that's not a bad idea actually, and I hadn't really thought of that. Ideally, I don't want to have to change how the .NET application is launched (e.g. setting environment variables necessary for the .NET Profiling API), but if that's not possible technically, I think the approach you suggest is probably the best I can do. Thanks again.

Comment: You just have to be wary if you have any other utilities that use the profiling API - you can normally tell if you look in the eventlog as the runtime will record when a profiler is attached to a process.